# variation on generalized assignment

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm looking to solve a constrained optimization problem. I believe it is a variant of the [generalized assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem).

I have *n* kinds of items, *x<sub>1</sub>* through *x<sub>n</sub>* and *m* kinds of bins *b<sub>1</sub>* through *b<sub>m</sub>*. There is an overall budget *w*. For a bin *b<sub>i</sub>*, each item *x<sub>j</sub>* has a profit *p<sub>ij</sub>* and a weight *w<sub>ij</sub>*. We want to:

find *x<sub>ij</sub>*, which indicates the number of items of type *j* in bin *i*
maximize sum(i=1 to m) sum(j=1 to n) *p<sub>ij</sub>* *x<sub>ij</sub>* 
subject to:
sum(i=1 to m) sum(j=1 to n) *w<sub>ij</sub>* *x<sub>ij</sub>* <= *w* (total weight budget)
sum(i=1 to m) *x<sub>ij</sub>* <= 1 (each item goes in 0 or 1 bins)
each *x<sub>ij</sub>* is equal to 0 or 1 (no partial or negative item assignments)

So this is identical to the generalized assignment problem as presented on Wikipedia, but there is an overall budget instead of a budget for each bin.

I'm wondering whether this maps to another named problem so I can read about known solutions.

Comment: Items weigh different amounts depending on what bin you put them in?

Comment: Let's consider the bins to be on separate planets :). I'm not actually using the concepts of "weight" and "profit" for my application, I just took the example from Wikipedia since the underlying equations were the same ones I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is variation of [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with *mn* items.

We can view different weights and profits in bins as different items. We have *mn* items *x<sub>11</sub>* ... *x<sub>mn</sub>*, where item *x<sub>ij</sub>* have weight *w<sub>ij</sub>* and profit *p<sub>ij</sub>*. The only difference from knapsack problem is that we can take at most one item from one "group" of items (items with same type). But regarding [dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem), this is simplification, because you don't need to take combinations of items in one group into account.